# WriteableBitmap.SaveJpeg

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, jpeg

The line wb.SaveJpeg in the code generates the error: System.Windows.Media.Imaging.WriteableBitmap' does not contain a definition for 'SaveJpeg' and no extension method 'SaveJpeg' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.Media.Imaging.WriteableBitmap' could be found

I've included as references: PresentationCore,PresentaionFramework, System.Windows.Forms,WindowsBase.

```
BitmapImage image = CaptureImageFromClipBoard();
WriteableBitmap wb = new WriteableBitmap(image);

using (var isf = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
{
    using (var fs = isf.CreateFile(path + "\\" + filename + ".jpg"))
    {   
        wb.SaveJpeg(fs, wb.PixelWidth, wb.PixelHeight, 10, 100);
    }
}
```

Here's the method CaptureImageFromClipBoard:

```
static public BitmapImage CaptureImageFromClipBoard()
{
    var img = new System.Windows.Controls.Image();
    var imgsrc = Clipboard.GetImage();
    img.Source = new FormatConvertedBitmap(imgsrc, PixelFormats.Bgr32, null, 0);

    JpegBitmapEncoder encoder = new JpegBitmapEncoder();
    MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
    BitmapImage bImg = new BitmapImage();

    encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(imgsrc));
    encoder.Save(memoryStream);

    bImg.BeginInit();
    bImg.StreamSource = new MemoryStream(memoryStream.ToArray());
    bImg.EndInit();

    memoryStream.Close();

    return bImg;
}
```

Comment: In order to save a bitmap, you will need a BitmapEncoder class... like you used int the CaptureImageFromClipBoard method. WriteAble doesn't mean "SaveAble" - it would allow you to write to the bitmap in memory instead.

Comment: i guess where i have encoder.Save(memorystream) -- I want to save this to a physical file, is this what would happen in its place? All i want to do is save the image i have to a file.

Answer (score 0):

I propose to go like this - NOTE: untested, typed from memory and the original post...

```
static public void SaveCapturedImageFromClipBoard(Stream target)
{
    var img = new System.Windows.Controls.Image();
    var imgsrc = Clipboard.GetImage();
    img.Source = new FormatConvertedBitmap(imgsrc, PixelFormats.Bgr32, null, 0);

    JpegBitmapEncoder encoder = new JpegBitmapEncoder();

    encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(imgsrc));
    encoder.Save(target);
}
```

and

```
using (var isf = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
{
     using (var fs = isf.CreateFile(path + "\\" + filename + ".jpg"))
     {
         SaveCapturedImageFromClipBoard(fs);
     }
}
```

Comment: Bad example and misleading. What is the use of the img variable? It's not being used in the later code.
The way I see it, you need only 3 lines - create Encoder, add a BitmapFrame from Clipboard contents and save to target stream.

Comment: The thing here is: the Clipboard.GetImage method is highly buggy and to avoid getting a blank image you have to first convert it into another (temp) image or implement the low level clipboard functions with interop. I need to check the specifics again. Also,  like I mentioned, it's typed from memory and just a modification of the original post.